# What would be a good way to represent a vector of hierarchical objects?

Tags: python, pandas, blaze

I have an object represented as nested dictionaries \ arrays
all objects in the set have the same schema, though the number of entries in arrays may vary from object to object
I'm looking for a good way to store this data, that will allow simple batch operations.
specifically, fast access to a column \ set of columns as numpy arrays is important (which is the main reason not to use a simple list of objects)

pandas with MultiIndex was my 1st idea, but I don't believe it can support variable length arrays

Comment: Can you provide an example of the data?

Comment: for example:
 {'name': 'john', 'cars':[{'make': 'mazda', 'licence_plate': 123}, {'make': 'ford', 'licence_plate': 456}]}

Comment: And then you would have a list of those dictionaries?  What's wrong with just a DataFrame `pd.DataFrame([('john', 'mazda', 123), ('john', 'ford', 456)], columns=['name', 'make', 'license_plate'])`?

Answer (score 2):

[pytables](http://www.pytables.org/) is a very solid option for this use case. It supports variable length arrays.

Comment: Are you sure arrays are supported a fields? I couldn't find a reference for this